# How do I exclude a pattern and then include back a pattern with Perforce Streams?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec, perforce-stream

I have a large depot with large binaries spread throughout in many subdirectories, but following a pattern. Some are only used in some workflows, and some are not used at all. The contents and layout of the repository comes from a third party framework, so moving things around, sadly, isn't an option.

I'm trying to create a client view that filters out most of the binaries, but includes only the ones build machines need for their workflow. I'm finding this difficult with streams.

As an example, let's say my depot looks like this:

```
//depot/mainline/plugins/rok/...
//depot/mainline/plugins/grok/...

//depot/mainline/dependency/not_used_1/...
//depot/mainline/dependency/not_used_2/...
//depot/mainline/dependency/used_a/...
//depot/mainline/dependency/used_b/...

//depot/mainline/third_party/dependency/not_used_3/...
//depot/mainline/third_party/dependency/used_ c/...

//depot/mainline/tools/gleep/...
//depot/mainline/tools/glorp/...
```

And say there are many more plugins, dependencies, and tools.

Each of these paths has a `bin` subdirectory with large binaries. I need some of them, but not all of them.

I want a client view that looks like this:

```
View:
    //depot/mainline/... //client/mainline
    -//depot/mainline/.../bin/... //client/mainline/.../bin/...
    //depot/mainline/tools/used_a/bin/... //client/mainline/tools/used_b/bin/...
    //depot/mainline/dependency/used_c/bin/... //client/mainline/dependencies/used_d/bin/...
```

I don't want to enumerate all the things I want to remove because that list might change. I want to enumerate things I need. It's also a shorter list. But, Perforce Streams won't allow embedded wildcards in `exclude` declarations. It does allow them in `Ignore` declarations, but then I can't selectively add them back in. The ignores are always added at the end of the view.

This used to be easy when I could specify my client view directly. Is there a way I can achieve what I want using Perforce Streams without explicitly listing every bin path I want to exclude?

Comment: You say you're not the one with authority to determine what goes in the repository -- but can you influence *where* in the repository they go?  Because adding a bunch of bloat to the mainline stream such that it's difficult to exclude is pretty bad practice.  The binaries should either be collected into a single top level directory that's easy to exclude, or ideally, in their own depot entirely.

Comment: Actually, looking at your client view, it looks like the root of the problem might be that you have a mainline stream with a bunch of independent projects under it.  This is backwards!  Streams are designed such that each "project" is supposed to be its own stream depot with its own mainline.

Comment: Sorry! I was probably misleading in constructing this contrived example...

Comment: 1. I can't really disrupt anyone's workflow for about 20 engineers. 2. This layout is part of a 3p framework we are using, since we want to rebase from time to time we kind of need to keep it the same as the source. 3. The projects are not actually independent projects, they are dependencies. Some don't have source, but we don't use all of them. And some are very big.

Comment: I tried to update the question to clarify your points.